# Changing order of object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Think of I have an object array as below:

```
var array = [
    { name: "A", position: "0" },
    { name: "B", position: "1" },
    { name: "C", position: "2" },
    { name: "D", position: "3" },
    { name: "E", position: "4" },
    { name: "F", position: "5" }
];
```

Let's say user dragged the element that has position 4 and dropped it on the element that has position 1.

```
var replacedItem = { name: "E", position: "4" };
var destinationItem = { name: "B", position: "1" };
```

How can I rearrange the positions of elements using javascript to have the array containing following values:

```
var array = [
    { name: "A", position: "0" },
    { name: "E", position: "1" },
    { name: "B", position: "2" },
    { name: "C", position: "3" },
    { name: "D", position: "4" },
    { name: "F", position: "5" }
];
```

Thanks,

Comment: shouldn't B be getting position 4?

Comment: you should be looking at array.splice this allows rearrangement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - destionNationItemIndex

4 - replacedItemIndex

You can try this:-

```
var removed = array.splice(4, 1);
array.splice(1, 0, removed[0]);
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    array[i].position = (parseInt(array[i - 1].position) + 1).toString();
}
```

Prints what you need:-

```
var array = [
    { name: "A", position: "0" },
    { name: "E", position: "1" },
    { name: "B", position: "2" },
    { name: "C", position: "3" },
    { name: "D", position: "4" },
    { name: "F", position: "5" }
]
```

Comment: It is a good practice to use the radix argument with `parseInt`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to move an element in two steps:

```
var a = [ ... ];
var temp = a.splice(4, 1); // remove element at index 4
a.splice(1, 0, temp[0]);   // insert the removed element at index 1
```

`splice()` returns an array of the removed elements (in this case, a 1-element array), which is why you need to subscript `temp`.

Since you only want to move the `name` properties around, one way would be to separate the array into two arrays, rearrange the array corresponding to the `name` property and recombine:

```
var fromIndex = 4, toIndex = 1;
// Step 1: collect names and positions in separate arrays
var names = [], positions = [];
array.forEach(function(elt) {
        this.names.push(elt.name);
        this.positions.push(elt.position);
    }, {names: names, positions: positions});
// Step 2: do a circular permutation of the names between the indexes (inclusive)
var temp = names.splice(fromIndex, 1);
names.splice(toIndex, 0, temp[0]);
// Step 3: recombine names and positions into an array of objects
var n = array.length;
array.length = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    array.push({name: names[i], position: positions[i]});
}
```

Comment: but this won't change the value of the position attribute of the object!

Comment: @AbdulJabbar -- Oops. Misread the problem. Will think about fixing this.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the simplest of logic to achieve that:

```
var array = [
    { name: "A", position: "0" },
    { name: "B", position: "1" },
    { name: "C", position: "2" },
    { name: "D", position: "3" },
    { name: "E", position: "4" },
    { name: "F", position: "5" }
];

var replacedItem = { name: "E", position: "4" };
var destinationItem = { name: "B", position: "1" };

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if(array[i].position == replacedItem.position)
        array[i].position = destinationItem.position;
    else if(array[i].position == destinationItem.position)
        array[i].position = replacedItem.position;
}
```

New Array will be:

```
var array = [
        { name: "A", position: "0" },
        { name: "B", position: "4" },
        { name: "C", position: "2" },
        { name: "D", position: "3" },
        { name: "E", position: "1" },
        { name: "F", position: "5" }
    ];
```

You simply need to swap their positions.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zk4ohgb7/1/)**

Comment: This sample does a simple swap operation and I think we don't need any iteration to do that. If you examine carefully the final state in my question, you see it's different from your result. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Even after swapping positions, your result does not match what OP needs.